# Session state with jQuery/Ajax and ASP.NET web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to consume an ASP.NET web service, using jQuery's Ajax methods.  I want the return type of the web service method to be JSON-formatted data, and I'm marking the method with these attributes:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public MyObject[] GetMyObjects(int pageIndex) {/*...*/}
```

I want to also return from the method some sort of value that would indicate whether the session has expired, either in the SOAP headers an output parameter.  How would I do this with jQuery syntax?  Should I wrap my `MyObject[]` array in a serializable ResponseType object that contains a SessionValid property and the payload?  Or is it possible to use SOAP headers and output parameters with jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I wrap my MyObject[] array in a serializable ResponseType object that contains a SessionValid property and the payload?

This is the way I usually go with.
Not time consuming to implement and very easy to maintain.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyReturn
{
  public MyObject[] MyObjectList { get; set; }
  public bool SessionExpired { get; set; }
}
```

Then handle it where you do the AJAX call.

*EDIT*: I usually only use

```
//...
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json", 
//...
```

in my AJAX calls to be sure the returned type is in JSON format.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing actually, before I posted my response, but I don't see an intuitive way to determine if the HttpContext's current session was created on the current request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely familiar with using session in SOAP web services.  However, I did stumble on **[this post](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/376610-webservice-session-sessionstate-soap)** which states that the JavaScript will need to account for cookies since this is how the session is maintained.

Although, SOAP may use a different method for tracking session via it's headers, so I don't know if this is accurate.

Comment: Thanks.  But is JScript/Infopath the same as JavaScript as implemented in a web browser?

Comment: Ok, after testing, it appears that session state is not being retained.  I'm going to have to figure out how to pass the cookies in the ajax call.

Comment: Ok, it's working after all.  I just had a couple bugs in my code.